# Attach header to all response()->json()->send() laravel;

Tags: json, laravel, http-headers

For some reasons I send JSON response from my helper/library instead of controller using below code:

```
response()->json(
    [
        "status"  => false,
        "message" => "This product is out of stock",
    ],
    200
)->send();
exit;
```

my problem is no middleware header if that response sent. How to attach header to all `response()->json()->send();exit;` function?

Below us my response header of default controller ):
[image]

Above response has all header from all middleware and below is my header response from `response()->json()->send();exit;`:

[image]

above not showing headers from the middleware.

I know I can send the header manually by add `->header('X-Header-One', 'Header Value')` like code below:

```
response()->json(
                [
                    'status'  => false,
                    'message' => 'This voucher is not for selected products',
                ]
            )->header('X-Header-One', 'Header Value')->send();
            exit;
```

But I already have so many that responses, and I dont want to try to [WET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself#DRY_vs_WET_solutions)ing my code.

Comment: why don't you create a middleware and apply there?

Comment: Middleware is not working on that , see my screenshot above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some digging, you could also create a Response Macro

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#response-macros

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ResponseMacroServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register the application's response macros.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Response::macro('custom', function ($value) {
            return Response::json($value)->headers();
        });
    }
}
```

Then in your code, just use

```
return response()->custom($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a middleware `SetHeader.php`

then

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class setHeader
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $request->headers->set('X-Header-One', 'Header Value');
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

like that you can add as may as headers and apply to those routes which you want to send

Comment: Middleware is not working on that response, that's why asked, if it worked like in controller the problem is solved

Comment: it should work as i m using same and for me it is working

Comment: No, maybe you use `return response()` not like me without return but put exit/die after that response()->json()->send();exit;,

Comment: try my code in your model or helper or library and you know what I mean

Comment: i think my code is set header to `request` and your code is set headers to `response`  becouse your checking headers which are come back from server and my code is while sending req. to server we modify the headers then it goes to controller with new headers

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur Middlewares does work for the responses if you inject it correctly. You can check Laravel's own throttling middleware to see it: 
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php

Comment: @SühaBoncukçu I didnt say "does work for the response" but "doesnt work on that response (my needs)". I need to return response on helper that called from controller, which mean it's running after all middleware executed. And I don't need throttling too. Thanks

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur I still think if you return the response instead of exiting the code, you should get the headers since it's part of the cycle. But I can see from the previous comments that exit is your choice so nothing to add :) Just wanted to share with future readers basically.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Controller.php`

Add a function and call it whatever you want

EG

```
public function MyCustomResponse()
{
  ... 
}
```

Then allow that to take in the params you want, in your case it is an array and an int, (data and status)

```
public function MyCustomResponse(array $data, int $status)
{
  ... 
}
```

Then handle the logic in there

```
public function MyCustomResponse(array $data, int $status)
{
  response()->json($data, $status)->header('X-Header-One', 'Header Value')->send();
}
```

Now when you want to use it, ensure that you are extending the controller where you have placed this code and just do

```
return $this->myCustomResponse($data, 200);
```

---

A better option depending on your need is to use a middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $request->headers->set( ... );
    return $next($request);
}
```

And apply to your route

Comment: thanks, it's nice idea, but I will try to wait for other idea first.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer to this question is already given, But I suggest using the power of the middleware concept. Middleware is not just working for requests but also works for the response.

By using the response macro we have to change the reference to use a custom function instead of json.

Here is the middleware code.

**SetResponseHeaders.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SetResponseHeaders
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        $response->header('X-Header-One', 'XValue');
        return $response;
    }
}
```

and don't forget to register the middleware.

**Http/Kernel.php**

```
protected $middleware = [
    // other middlewares
    \App\Http\Middleware\SetResponseHeaders::class,
]
```

**Special notes:-** If you are using the CORS concept then you have the cors.php file under the config folder. In my case, I am using `fruitcake/laravel-cors` package. so you have to expose the header otherwise you will not get the value.

**cors.php**

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
    | or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
    | in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
    |
    | To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
    |
    */

    // other config

    'exposed_headers' => ['X-Header-One'],
]
```